# Given two Joda DateTime objects, how can I check if one is 30 minutes or above before another one?

Tags: java, datetime, compare, jodatime

I want to check if the current time is 30 minutes before a DateTime object, how can this be achieved in Joda DateTime?

Comment: Exactly 30 minutes before or not greater than 30 minutes?

Comment: For example, current time is 18:00 and the datetime I want to check against is 18:30. This should return true since it is now 30 mins or under. On the underhand if it was 17:59:59 then it would be false. Anything after 18:00 should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static boolean inTime(DateTime time, int minutesBefore){
    DateTime start = DateTime.now();
    DateTime end = now.plusMinutes(minutesBefore);
    return !(time.isBefore(start) || time.isAfter(end));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but can you explain the trust interval?

Comment: @JohnathanAu I edited my sample according to your requirements.